# Oracle SQL Trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I want to prevent the database from storing any values bigger than 20 into a table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Dont_Allow
AFTER INSERT ON Cities
FOR EACH ROW

WHEN (new.IDCity > 20)

BEGIN
   dbms_output.put_line('  Failed to insert ' || :new.IDCity);
   delete from orase where IDCity=:new.IDCity;
END;
```

While this does work in terms of not actually adding anything with an `ID > 20`, every time the trigger tries to do its magic, this shows up:

> ORA-04091: table SYSTEM.ORASE is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
>   ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.DONT_ALLOW", line 6
>   ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.DONT_ALLOW'

What's a proper way of doing what I want?

---

### EDIT:

I've decided to use a trigger for this:

After a new row is inserted into `Employees`, a trigger checks the new guy's salary and if it's above 21 units / hour, it takes 5% off management's bonus. Lame, but hey - I'm using a trigger to solve a problem I don't have: the outcome won't be pretty.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Bite_Bonus
AFTER INSERT ON Employees
FOR EACH ROW

WHEN (new.HourSalary > 20)

BEGIN
   update Management set Bonus = Bonus - 5/100 * Bonus;
END;
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a `BEFORE` update trigger for this, and raising an exception if the id is invalid?

Comment: See my answer for a proper solution for this. IF, however you do use a trigger, then `AFTER` is definitely wrong. You need a `BEFORE INSERT` or `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger there, and, as Mat said, raise an exception if necessary.

Comment: @Mat is there a NOP for oracle? how can I abort the statements from being executed from within the trigger?

Comment: @Buffalo: what is a NOP?

Comment: @Mat NO-OPERATION. If a condition is met inside my BEFORE INSERT trigger (new.IDCity > 20), I want to abort the insert.

Comment: Then please read my first comment, TC1's comment, and my answer which all three say how you abort an update. You do not do that with a NOOP instruction, you do that by raising an exception. (`NULL;` is a noop statement in PL/SQL if you need one for other reasons.)

Comment: Your edit completely changes the purpose of the trigger.  So you were just making up some excuse to use a trigger in the first place?  What a waste of everybody's time.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a `TRIGGER` for that, you should be using a `CHECK`, like `CONSTRAINT city_id_below_20 CHECK (IDCity < 20)`. You can use `ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT` to put it on an existing table.

Comment: this is for an assignment. I *must* use some kind of trigger; this came to mind first.

Comment: Even then, you'd definitely want a `BEFORE` to check for that. As I said, that's really not what triggers are used for though, and if I'd be your teacher I'd put a quite crappy grade for a use-case such as that... A common thing to use them for (at least one that I've seen in a ton of business apps) is auditing changes to a table. Pretty sure you can find other examples on google if you need them.

Answer (score 5):

As TC1 indicated, the proper way to enforce this sort of requirement is to use a constraint.

If you are forced to use the inferior approach because this is a school assignment, you most likely want to raise an exception in your trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Dont_Allow
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Cities
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (new.IDCity > 20)
BEGIN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'IDCity cannot exceed 20 so rejecting invalid value: ' || :new.IDCity );
END;
```

Comment: I amended the trigger to fire on UPDATE as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to use a trigger for this, make it a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, not an `AFTER INSERT` - you don't want that insert to happen at all. Trying to "undo" it after the fact is not a good approach.

To abort the insert, all you need to do is raise an exception within that trigger. Probably the best thing for this is to [raise an application error](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm#sthref2006).